# How to make an xeditable select input mandatory (required) in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, x-editable, angular-xeditable

I have an AngularJS project that uses Angular Bootstrap and I use the [Angular-xeditable](https://vitalets.github.io/angular-xeditable/#select-local) library for some edit-in-place fields in a table.

One of the inputs I have is a "select" input, i.e. a drop-down list that allows a user to select one option. (editable-select in xeditable).
I am trying to make this input mandatory when saving the form, but I cannot find a way to do this. Similar to all the x-editable controls I would expect that I can simply add an e- prefix to the standard angular directive to apply that directive to the xeditable control, that is, I *should* be able to add e-ng-required="true" to my control to make it mandatory. Yet this does not work. I do not get any errors when I add this, but it doesn't "do" anything. I can still save my form without selecting an item.

The following is a code sample of what I'm trying to do:

```
<form editable-form name="tableform" onaftersave="saveSubmissions()" oncancel="cancel()">
    <table>
        <!--Define table headings and columns...-->
        <!--Define an ng-repeat to display each row-->
        <tr ng-repeat="currentRow in dataRows">
            <!--Add some columns for the row-->
            <!--Add the select/drop-down column pertaining to this question-->
            <td>
                <span editable-select="currentRow.vendorID" e-ng-options="x.vendorId as x.name for x in vendors" e-form="tableform" e-ng-required="true">
                    {{showVendor(currentRow)}}
                </span>
            </td>
            <!--Add some more columns for each row-->
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

Even though I've set e-ng-required="true" on the element, it does nothing. How can I make the selection of an item mandatory using xeditable? I have searched for examples but couldn't find anything helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately required doesn't work with form validators as stated in the following links

[Required field validation is not working](https://github.com/vitalets/angular-xeditable/issues/76)

[Validation field form using tag "form" with angular-xeditable](https://github.com/vitalets/angular-xeditable/issues/635)

You have to manually check and set the validity of input onbeforesave and set validity of input element.

html

```
<span editable-select="currentRow.vendorID" e-ng-options="x.vendorId as x.name for x in vendors" e-form="tableform" e-name="vendor" onbeforesave="checkValidity()">
    {{showVendor(currentRow)}}
</span>
```

js

```
$scope.checkValidity = function(){
    if(valid){
        $scope.tableform.$setValidity("vendor", true);
    }
    else{
        $scope.tableform.$setValidity("vendor", false);
    }
}
```

Comment: It worked to do the validation in the onbeforesave method as mentioned here. I could not quite get the $setValidity to work in the js function as NTP mentions. I have found that it is sufficient to return an error message in the validation function if invalid and xeditable does the rest for you to mark the form as invalid. i.e. the js validation function I used was along the lines of: if (invalid) { return "Please select a vendor"; } without the need for an else clause and without having to manually set the validity on the tableform.

Comment: I am glad I was able to help.